# Getting all Okta app config using Terraform

Tags: terraform, okta, terraform0.12+

I am a newbie to Terraform. Looking to backup all the Okta configuration(Apps, Groups and Policies) using Terraform. As it doesn't have any loops, I am stuck on how to get all the app config.

For example, if I want to get the config for a particular SAML app, I can use this data source.
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/okta/okta/latest/docs/data-sources/app_saml

How can I dynamically call this to get the config for all apps in Okta? Also, is there a way to download these configs to a local file?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot user the terraform data source you linked to look up Okta config that isn't managed in terraform. The data source will only tell you things about resources already configured in terraform.

You'll have to do a `terraform import` for each resource, which is a total pain. See https://www.terraform.io/cli/import#currently-state-only

Honestly, I'd recommend a new Okta org that will be exclusively managed from terraform.